# Proving a complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble proving that
$$\lim_{z\to z_0} z^{2}+c = z_{0}^{2}+c$$
where $c$ is a complex constant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $\lim_{z\to z_0} z^2+c=z_0^2+c \Leftrightarrow |z^2+c-(z_0^2+c)|\to 0 \text{ for }z\to z_0$.

Comment: So far, I have tried that with the end result of

Comment: So far, I have tried that with the end result of $$\left | z ^{2} - z_{0}^2\right | = \left | z-z_0 \right | \left | z+z_0 \right |$$. However, I am having difficulty going from there. If we were able to show that $$\left | z-z_0 \right | \leq  \left | z+z_0 \right |$$, this would be much simpler. However that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: You could show and use that $$|z^2-z_0^2|\leqslant C\,|z-z_0|$$ for every $z$ close enough to $z_0$, for some suitable $C$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that *for any* (real) $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists (a real) $\;\delta>0\;$ such that

$$\;|z-z_0|<\delta\implies |(z^2+c)-(z_0^2+c)|<\epsilon\;.$$

So this is about proving **existence**. Now:

$$|(z^2+c)-(z_0^2+c)|=|z-z_0|\,|z+z_0|\stackrel ?<\epsilon$$

Can you now define *a* $\;\delta>0\;$ that will fulfill what is needed as described above? Further hint: you're interested in values of $\;z\;$ within a pretty small neighborhood of $\;z_0\;$.

Comment: @Did Thanks, typo edited and further explanation added. I missed that square there...